# Can I use powertop when I am plugged into a power source?

Tags: usb, power-management

I am plugging into an embedded device using an usb cable which serve as both communication and power. I am trying to use powertop to only monitor the power usage of the device and my software as my device frequently experience loss of power, despite changing the USB cable, the laptop attached to it and even connecting to it with a powered USB hub.

It seems it is not measuring any value when my application is using the onboard camera. Here is a snippet of the powertop report I have captured:

```
 *  *  *   Overview of Software Power Consumers   *  *  *

Usage;Wakeups/s;GPU ops/s;Disk IO/s;GFX Wakeups/s;Category;Description;PW Estimate
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;
```

Do I need to do something before running powertop?